# Finding duplicate values in multiple rows in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database table with this sample data:

```
 ProductID     GenericID       MG
 ---------------------------------
    1           1           2g 
    1           2           5g
    2           2           5g
    3           1           2g
    3           2           5g
    4           1           2g
    5           1           2g
    5           3           7g
    6           2           5g
    7           1           2g
    8           1           2g
```

I want to find out the query to select data

1. if I select 'ProductID=1' then the query should check what 'GenericID' are associated with 'ProductID=1'
2. In above data case if user select 'ProductID=1' then query will check 'GenericID=1' and 2 are associated with 'ProductID=1'.
3. Then after I want to go through all rows and select those rows who has the same Unique 'ProductID' and also having only 'GenericID=1 and 2'.
4. as in above case the final output will be as shown below....
5. I select 'ProductID=1' and output has four rows, because only ProductId 3 has same 'GenericID' as were of 'ProductId=1'

If I select only `ProductId=1` then I want to get all the rows with the same exact set of `GenericID` values as `ProductID=1`, which is the set `{ 1, 2 }` in my sample data. I am struggling with the query logic.

For example - I select `ProductID=1`, this is the output that I want is as follows, because `ProductID` 3 has the same set of `GenericID` values as `ProductID` 1.

```
     ProductID    GenericID     MG
     -------------------------------
        1              1        2g     
        1              2        5g
        3              1        2g
        3              2        5g
```

`GenericID` can be on or multiple dynamic values.

Another example - if I select `ProductID=7`, this is the output I want:

In this example -  It will only get those results that are having only GenericID=1 because ProductID=7 has only GenericID=1. any set of productID which is having 'GenericID=1' and also that set includes other 'GenericID' will be neglected.

```
      ProductID    GenericID     MG
      ------------------------------
        7              1         2g    
        8              1         2g
        4              1         2g
```

I need to find out the query to select the required output.
I want all of the products that have the same set of generic id's as the predicate product.

Comment: What is your question here, you haven't asked anything.

Comment: I want to find out query from the table. as shown in outputs

Comment: *"I want to find out query from the table"* What does that mean?  Tables don't store queries, you use queries to get data from a table. Where does the row  in your second result set, where `ProductID` has a value of `3` and `MG` has a value of `'2g'` come from, when no rows in your sample data have that value?

Comment: I think your second sample output is wrong, you forgot ProductID 1. First one too, seems like it should have ProductId 7.

Comment: out put will be only matched, if all genericsID will be matched

Comment: @ArslanSadiq Well, product 1 and product 7 both have a `GenericID` value of 1. So...?

Comment: Basically idea is to find the alternative productID which are having same Generic ID.

Comment: `ProductID` 1 has the same `GenericID` as `ProductID` 7. Both of them have a `GenericID` of 1. If you're saying it's correct that the first output correctly excludes product 7, and that it's correct that the second output excludes product 1, then I can't comprehend your requirement.

Comment: Ah, I have figured it out. You want all of the products that have the same *set* of generic id's as the predicate product. Oh well, too late

Comment: @allmhuran yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218043/discussion-between-arslan-sadiq-and-allmhuran).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  GenericID in (SELECT GenericID FROM yourtable WHERE ProductID=1)
```

**Update:**
If the whole set of GenericIDs needs to match, this should work (assuming ProductID, GenericID is unique):

```
WITH yourtable_gids AS (
SELECT
  ProductID,
  STRING_AGG(GenericID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GenericID) as GenericIDs
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ProductID
)
SELECT y.*
FROM yourtable y
JOIN yourtable_gids yg ON y.ProductID=yg.ProductID
WHERE
  yg.GenericIDs in (SELECT GenericIDs FROM yourtable_gids WHERE ProductID=1)
```

Comment: this will return all the rows even if their count doesn't match with product id 1.

Comment: Updated to match based on the full set of GenericIDs.

Answer (score 0):

So if i interpret the question right it's
I select on a product Id, and want to additionaly have every product with the same generic IDs as the ones I got.

```
select * from products 
where productID = X 
or genericId in (select genericId from products where product ID = X)
```

This should be the answer if I got your question right.

Comment: Saw the answer from Alex and realized the first filter is basically redundant. His is more right.

Comment: this will return all the rows even if their count doesn't match with product id 1. i want only those products who has the exact match of GenericID as of ProductID1